# Emacs restore desktop interrupts with message "apply: Searching for program: No such file or directory, rcsdiff"

Tags: debugging, emacs, version-control

When I restart emacs, desktopaid's dta-load-session tries to restore my session (all files and windows), but breaks with the error message

```
apply: Searching for program: No such file or directory, rcsdiff
```

How can I find out which file makes emacs search for rcsdiff so that I can kill that buffer for the next time?

(Emacs 25.1.1 on MacOS)

Comment: To troubleshoot this, `M-x setq debug-on-error t` and examine the backtrace.

Comment: `rcsdiff` is used by the old `rcs` back-end so I guess Emacs thinks you are visiting a version-controlled file.  Do you have files whose names end with `,v` by any chance?  Having an `RCS` directory next to a file might also be a trigger.

Comment: @tripleee: thanks for the tip, that helps already. However, the correct invocation is `M-x set-variable debug-on-error t`

Comment: Yeah, sorry for the wrong command and thanks for the follow-up.

Answer (score 0):

Install  the  [Elisp Bug Hunter](https://github.com/Malabarba/elisp-bug-hunter).   It will automatically find the bug for you. It will ask you  series of question when you see the error and when you don't based on bisecting your initialization files.